# How do I get the text of an <option> component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm writing a test that tests a function that outputs an array of `<option>` `Component`s. I want to test that the `<option>`s have the correct values and display the correct text.

I can check the value of each `<option>` like so:

```
const generatedArrayOfOptionComponents = functionToTest();
const firstOptionComponent = generatedArrayOfOptionCompononts[0];
const optionValue = firstOptionComponent.props.value;
```

How can I get the text that `firstOptionComponent` will show when it is rendered?

---

Answers to similar questions typically involve adding an event handler and getting the text of the selected `<option>` when it changes. This won't work for me because I'm in a testing environment. In this test, all I have are the `Component` objects returned by the test - there's no DOM environment, and this particular test doesn't use Enzyme. How can I get the `<option>` component's text from the raw component instance itself?

Comment: How are you evening creating the "compnent" if there is no DOM?

Comment: My function looks like this: `function functionToTest() { return [(<option value={'hello'}>Hello</option>), (<option> value={'world'}>World</world>)]; }` So, using JSX, `React.createElement` is being called to instantiate each of the `<option>` components. I guess that might involve the shadow DOM if `React.createElement` automatically sets it up - I hadn't really thought about that. But since this is in a test environment with no browser and without Enzyme, I'm pretty sure there's no 'real' DOM.

Comment: How are you testing your code without some sort of browser environment? If you are, what's the point?

Comment: I want to make sure that the function under test returns the correct results. Most of our tests do use Enzyme to test individual components, but since this function uses React internally, I have to work with the React Component instances that React generates directly.

Comment: I see. I'm not sure how you can test what is arguably DOM functionality without the DOM.

Comment: You probably want [ReactDOMServer](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom-server.html)

Comment: @Hamms That works for me! It's a bit of a workaround, but it definitely gets the job done. Can you please write that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of situations in which it's nice to interact with the rendered products of a React component in a situation where you don't have a DOM; tests are one, isomorphic serverside React is another, and I'm sure there are more.

In those situations, [ReactDOMServer](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom-server.html) is there for you.